# Trouble with LibGDX resetting origin on an already rotated actor

Tags: rotation, libgdx

If I do:

```
actor.setOrigin(0, 0);
actor.setRotation(45);
actor.setOrigin(actor.getWidth() / 2, actor.getHeight() / 2);
```

It appears that on the last `setOrigin` call, the actor gets repositioned to the location it would've been if `actor.setRotation(45)` would have been called after its latest origin was set.

What do I do to make it so that the latest origin of the actor is only used for future "scale" and "rotation" actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i looked in the source code of libgdx, and i'll tell you the short answer.

Basically when you set the origin or the rotation, you just change a variable named "originx", "originy" and "rotation". So every call to setOrigin will overwrite the values set in previous calls.

And every time you draw the actor, it recalculates the bounds using the current variable.

To be clear, setOrigin looks like this :

```
public void setOrigin (float originX, float originY) {
    this.originX = originX;
    this.originY = originY;
}
```

So the precedent setOrigin is lost.

Answer (score 0):

The reposition of the actor itself in your case does not change, but the position of the displayed sprite or texture will change.

It is calculated in this order:

```
Position -> Origin -> Scale -> Rotation
```

> See: [Sprite.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/e03b757caed03d69083ab9c4f5ffe9e594fef1e3/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java#L473) (method: "getVertices ()")

When you change the Origin point of an already rotated element, the point in the plane around which the rotation occurs changes and the sprite will be drawn in a different place (the actor's position in this case does not change).